# how to implement search functionality in a template that is built on bootstrap (Metronic) without backend?

Tags: javascript, html, search, metronic

After buying the template which contains alot of pages and components, i tried the searchbar but it only shows dummy page to show how will search return.

how can i make it search in the template for pages or components without backend such as using JavaScript and jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this [jquery plugin](https://github.com/stidges/jquery-searchable) i.e. "a jQuery plugin to search through elements as you type" or buy this template from [themeforest](https://themeforest.net/item/wiseboard-responsive-multipurpose-admin-template/19608853?s_rank=17)